# PHP UserAgent for IE 10.0 does not match

Tags: php, windows, internet-explorer, redirect, user-agent

The PHP redirect should working for IE version 8 and below. version 9 is working fine but IE 10.0 is not working with this code (looks like IE 10.0 gets dismissed or etc.):

```
if ( preg_match("/(?i)msie [1-8]/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header("Location: http://www.XYXYXYX.com");
    }
```

my goal would be, that the redirecting should only work for MS IE 8 and below.

Thanks alot.

---

**EDIT2 / SOLUTION:**

i should have changed my code to this:

```
if ( preg_match("/(?i)msie [1-8]\./",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
header("Location: http://www.XYXYXYX.com");
}
```

The trailing dot ensures the version number is only one digit.

Comment: There is a [new user-agent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/15/the-ie10-user-agent-string.aspx) for IE10

Comment: It does not work perfect. The same problem will be there once IE 20 gets release.

Comment: Apart from MSIE 10 being an obvious problem, why did you use this regular expression in the first place? Have you actually tested your fallback site with IE 2 or 3 or 4 and found that it works? If not, why do you bother redirecting those browsers (assuming that anyone is actually using them)?

Comment: @Sven: IE 11 has changed the UA string much more radically, the MSIE token does not appear anymore. And anyway, we cannot make any predictions about the future.

Comment: @Jon Yes, user agent sniffing is evil. It is even more evil if you want to predict the future without changing your code.

Comment: @jon thats true - i dont have any troubles with IE 11 cause there is no MSIE token and its feeling like Firefox or Chrome (i mean the IE 11)

Comment: I'll echo others who are saying that user agent sniffing is just a bad bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check the FULL version number.

```
if ( preg_match("/(?i)msie [1-8]\.0/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header("Location: http://www.XYXYXYX.com");
}
```

Note the ".0" suffix that gets checked. That way, you'll never need to change the code again for versions of 10, 20, 30 or even 80 that might come.

Ah, well, IE 5.5 was once released...

```
if ( preg_match("/(?i)msie [1-8]\./",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header("Location: http://www.XYXYXYX.com");
}
```

Check that after the ONE single digit, there is a dot. If it is not a dot, it probably is a digit from a two-digit version number like "10".

Answer (score 3):

I think a more reliable way of redirecting for IE would be to do it via javascript using conditional HTML statements:

```
<!--[if lte IE8]>
<script>
    window.location.assign('http://www.XYXYXYX.com')
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thats true - but i am also checking the URL string for special chars - so php is for me the best option

Comment: Checking URL and browser are two different things. I don't see any reason to not use both conditional HTML **and** PHP...

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match('/(?i)msie (6|7|8|9|10)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
```

or

```
 if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-9]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // if IE <= 10
   echo "version is less than 10"; //rest of your code
} else  if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [10]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // if IE = 10
   echo "version is IE 10"; //rest of your code
}
else
{
    // if not 10
     echo " other browser"; //rest of your code

}
```